# Display missing values of specific column based on another specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, nan

this is my problem

Let's say I have 2 columns on the dataframe which look like this:

```
 Type   | Killed
_______ |________
 Dog        1
 Dog       nan
 Dog       nan
 Cat        4
 Cat       nan
 Cow        1
 Cow       nan
```

I would like to display all missing value in Killed according to the Type and count them

My desire outcome would look something like this:

```
Type | Sum(isnull)
Dog       2
Cat       1
Cow       1
```

Is there anyway to display this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
print (df.ix[df.Killed.isnull(), 'Type'].value_counts().reset_index(name='Sum(isnull)'))

  index  Sum(isnull)
0   Dog            2
1   Cow            1
2   Cat            1
```

Or aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), it seems faster:

```
print (df[df.Killed.isnull()]
            .groupby('Type')['Killed']
            .size()
            .reset_index(name='Sum(isnull)'))

  Type  Sum(isnull)
0  Cat           1
1  Cow           1
2  Dog           2
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [30]: %timeit (df.ix[df.Killed.isnull(), 'Type'].value_counts().reset_index(name='Sum(isnull)'))
100 loops, best of 3: 5.36 ms per loop

In [31]: %timeit (df[df.Killed.isnull()].groupby('Type')['Killed'].size().reset_index(name='Sum(isnull)'))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.02 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

I can get you both `isnull` and `notnull`

```
isnull = np.where(df.Killed.isnull(), 'isnull', 'notnull')
df.groupby([df.Type, isnull]).size().unstack()
```

[image]